# Why do booleans behave differently in module js vs common js?

Tags: javascript, boolean

I have a quick script that I initially wrote in common.js and when it was finished I wanted to write a driver script showing the function and changed the type to module.js.

The script traverses a graph to find the shortest path and I keep track of visited nodes using an array, with elements set to true/false if it was visited.

The values for every visit are set to false:

```
  let visit = new Array(9);

  for (let i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
    visit[i] = new Array(9); 
    for (let j = 0; j <= 8; j++) {
      visit[i][j] = false;
    }
  }
```

The root node visit is changed to true:

```
visit[(rootNode[0], rootNode[1])] = true;
```

Then as the script progresses, touched nodes are changed to true which is where the error happens.

```
visit[x][y] = true;
```

Running the script in common.js gives the correct output. Running the script in module.js throws an error, saying:

> TypeError: Cannot create property '1' on boolean 'true'

Where 1 is the x value of the visited node.

Why is the behavior different?

Edit: The issue was with ES6 Modules requiring strict mode. My typo with the parenthesis worked perfectly fine in CommonJS on the edge cases I was testing but not on the regular tests. Fixing the typo made it work everywhere, thanks for the help.

Comment: `visit[(rootNode[0], rootNode[1])] = true;` doesn't do what you think - it's identical to `visit[rootNode[1]] = true;` and sets `visit[n] = true` (what `n` is depends on `rootNode[1]` whatever that is ... therefore `visit[n][1]=true` is like trying to set `true[1]=true` - which can't be done of course

Comment: What do you mean when you say "module.js" and "common.js"? I think you mean ES modules (commonly termed ESM or ES6 modules) and CommonJS, a module system that predates 2015 and the standardization of modules at the language level. Using standard terminology helps when discussing module systems.

Comment: `visit[(rootNode[0], rootNode[1])]` should be `visit[rootNode[0]][rootNode[1]]`

Comment: "*Running the script in common.js gives the correct output*" - no it doesn't. "*Running the script in module.js throws an error*" - yes, because ES6 module code is implicitly [strict](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

Comment: @JaromandaX I see how I made a mistake with the parenthesis and with that change it does now work in ES6 Modules. I'm still curious as why the first version works CommonJS without the fix though.

Comment: the code as presented would also break in commonjs, so, my guess is your commonjs and ESModuels code was different